# Getting java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate a decimal value but I am getting the above error. My x is 464564646645 and my y is 1241190000. I want to calculate the value z as
z=(y/x)*100
My code is as follows

```
String p= holdingsValues.get(0).
                replaceAll(",", "");
        BigDecimal k= BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(p));
        BigDecimal j=BigDecimal.valueOf(treasuryAdjustedTOS);
        BigDecimal o=k.divide(j).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

I want o to be 0.2672 but I am getting the above exception.

Comment: Only use the single-parameter _divide_ method when you know the quotient has a _"terminating"_ decimal.  Otherwise, I typically use _x.divide(y, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)_ where _20_ is the number of decimal digits, or even, _x.divide(y, MathContext.DECIMAL32)_.